# How to feed the IP of the device automatically in android

Tags: java, android, ip-address, android-networking

At the moment, I am giving the emulator IP address manually. After doing some research,I found out that If my device is connected to Wifi, I can use the following method.

`WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());`

But in my case it is not connected to wifi(Connected to LAN),How can I do it in this scenario ?

This what I have at the moment. I would like to have my app choose its IP ADDRESS automatically.

`String url = "0.0.0.0"; // emulator ip
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);`

Comment: try using 127.0.0.1 for the ip

Comment: I dont want to feed Ip manually. I would like to get automatically. If I feed the local IP, will it choose automatically ? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
try {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                Log.i(TAG, "***** IP="+ ip);
                return ip;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
}
return null;
}
```

using getHostAddress : IP=fe70::75ca:a16d:ea5a:.......

using hashCode and Formatter you will get the actual IP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have on equestion `formatIpAddress()` seems to be deprecatedAPI. Will it do the job ?

Comment: The deprecation is because the function doesn't support ipv6 and WifiInfo. Just use formatIpAddress() because it works and add @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") to get rid of the warning. Thank u

Comment: okie then. I will use it. This might be a stupid question. Can I just feed the method directly like this `mediaplayer.setDataSource(getLocalIpAddress())` or should I assign it to variable and feed it in.

Comment: Yes you can give like above.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. But it doesn't seem to be working. I am using inside a thread. Does it have anything to do with it

Comment: I am using this in two places. One is with mediaplayer and other one at  `inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(getLocalIpAddress());`

Comment: first let me know whether you are  getting the ip or not

Comment: yes I am getting an Ip. `***** IP=15.2.0.10`. This is the error which I am getting in `java.net.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: from where you are fetching the audio file?

Comment: from a remote server with a target Ip and port.

Comment: if it is xampp, make sure that that is accessible publicly.

Comment: Lanke. Actually the local Ip which I get it is reversed somehow `15.2.0.10`. But original Ip of the emulator is `10.0.2.15`

Comment: then once give a try to this https://www.android-examples.com/get-display-ip-address-of-android-phone-device-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Varma Lanke works fine. But it returns the IP in reverse order. In order to solve that

Instead of this line

`String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());`

Use this

`String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress();`

For more details. Have a look here [getting device Ip](https://www.android-examples.com/get-display-ip-address-of-android-phone-device-programmatically/)